# Joining data based on ranking of building size per tax parcel using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-joins, spatial-join, fuzzy-logic

I have two data sets.  Each data set has a Parcel ID and square footage for building footprints.  One was created by a government agency for tax assessment. The other by a small operation that traced the footprints of buildings from aerial imagery. There is no common attribute file between the buildings, only the tax parcels. We processed the footprints to find area (ft^2), but the data set do not match.  I would like to join the government tax database to the file of the traced building footprints.

Does anyone know of a way to join the buildings by parcel by relative size?

[image: Excel Worksheet showing area of footprints on one parcel.]

I am using ArcMAP 10.x
Sublime Text 3.0
MS Excel 2016

Windows 7 Pro
Intel i7-4930k 3.40GHz 
64 GB RAM
64-bit OS
Two NVIDIA 1080 GPU

Comment: Sort them both in ascending order and join. Risky thing though

Comment: Which one is the matching field (Parcel ID)? Does the Tax Data have a spatial component or is it just a table? Are you trying to find the largest building for each Parcel ID or match each building with its row in the tax table?

Comment: Is the Parcel ID a common attribute (do both datasets have Parcel ID, do they match)? If it is, you can use Parcel ID to join the tables.  If they are both spatial tables, you can use a spatial join.

Comment: @Michael, the matching field is the Parcel ID, the table above is the result of two tables that were merged.  The Tax data can be referenced by address and Parcel ID.  The addresses, after being concatenated do not match the addressing pins from an addressing file, nor do those pins reference the building footprints.  My goal is to join all of the assessor's data to the building footprints.

Comment: @jbalk, both data set do have a common attribute, Parcel ID.  The issue is that there are multiple buildings per parcel.  If there was only one building per Parcel that solution would work.

Comment: @FelixIP,  that is were I am right now, sorting and making risky joins.  The data is for a large data set so it is going to be very time consuming to truth the data.  Developing a methodology to sort the data took a couple days, and the solution I have isn't great.  It would be really great to have a python script pick this up for me and spit out the numbers.  Maybe I should reframe the question to the python community?

Comment: If you want one record only per parcel then perhaps dissolve by parcel id.. Would a multipart geometry with simplified fields suit your needs? An ArcGis join should be able to join the buildings to the tax records with parcel id on a one-to-one relation.

Comment: Are them 2 separate (equal length) sets? If yes, just use sort on each, calculate sequential fields and join

Comment: With no answers offered and lots of comments made I think now is the time to use the [edit] button to heavily revise your question to try and make what you are asking clearer.